# User Control dock inside Tab Page Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, dock, tabpage, user-controls

I have a TabControl. I add tab pages at runtime. On top of tabPage i add User Control at runtime.

Inside user Control i have richtextbox.

So its like TabControl-->TabPage--->UserControl-->RichTextBox & other controls.
I want my richtextbox to completely fill the space when i maximize. I tried Dock property and panel but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? What happened? What exactly do you want?

Comment: updated my previous post. pls refer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear what is your real problem, but just by guessing:

To me it seems that `Dock.Fill` can not fail in this condition. What can happen, IMHO, is that `TabControl` doesn't resize, so its children (richtextbox too) do not change their client area size. 
In other words

- Set `Dock.Fill` property on your `RichText` box
- Check out `TabControl`'s `Dock`, or `Anchor` properties.

Hope this helps.